# How do I use a random number?

Tags: lua

[image: 1]

I have tried 2 methods and they are both in the screenshot. How do I use random? I would be so happy if someone solves this one for me.

Comment: after 3 hours of self riddling, I got it working! no worries!

Answer (score 3):

Here, we are running into several problems with lua syntax and it's internals. First, let's understand how `random` works.

#### #1. The Random Problem.

---

When you get a random number from lua, it's not really random. This is because true randomness is practically impossible; It is a lot more effort than it is worth.

For this reason, Lua (and many other languages) have "cheated"- they instead use very large numbers to calculate the result of `random`.

*Disclaimer: I do not know how Lua's random function works. This is a generic random function that is in the same caliber as Lua's.*

---

To start with, we need a truly random number. For this, we use `randomseed`. Whenever we call `randomseed`, the `random` state is *completely erased*.

Consider the following code:

```lua
print(math.random(1,4))
print(math.random(1,4))
print(math.random(1,4))
```

Run this code. Run it a lot. No matter how many times you run it, it will always be the same four numbers. This is because lua's random function is just *math*, it's not really random.

Let's look at this: We start with a random seed, the current time.

```lua
math.randomseed(os.clock()*100000)
print(math.random(1,4))
print(math.random(1,4))
print(math.random(1,4))
```

Every time you run this, the numbers will be unique. This is because we take the current time as the seed, so the `random` is always in a scrambled state. Likewise,

```lua
math.randomseed(2)
print(math.random(1,4))
```

This code will always output `3`.

To solve this, let's change your code a little bit.

```lua
math.randomseed(os.clock() * 10000)
function Behavior:Awake()
    self.timer = 0
    place = math.random(1,4)
end
```

This should work, because it does not consistently reset the state. If it does not- let me know and I shall update with another solution.

#### #2. Lua Variables

---

You displayed some initial code:

```lua
function Behavior:Awake()
    self.Timer = 0
    place = 1, 4
end
```

This does not generate a random value. It instead follows some lesser-known lua syntax.
Consider the following code:

```lua
local a,b = "a","b"
```

This demonstrates the code rule. If you haven't guessed it by now, lua assigns variables sequentially. When you define a variable:

```lua
local a
```

You may provide any amount of values to fill this variable (separated by `,` of course). However, Lua only chooses the first one.

```lua
local a = 1,2,3,4,"and to infinity!"
print(a) --> 1
```

You can do the same for variables:

```lua
local first, second, last = 1,2,3,4,5,6,"and beyond..."
print(first,second,last) --> 1, 2, 3
```

This is useful for multiple reasons. For example, you can return multiple values from a single function:

```lua
function awesome(a)
    return (a == "sauce"), ("awesome "..a)
end
local isAwesome, Text = awesome("sauce")
print(isAwesome, Text) --> true, "awesome sauce"
```

...You can swap two variables around without needing a third one...

```lua
local a,b = b,a
```

This is also used a lot in `pcall`, which catches errors (so if part of your code errors- you can tell, and stop it)

```lua
function IWillError()
    error("told you so...")
end

local Success,Fail = pcall(IWillError)
print(Success, Fail) --> false (the code errored), "told you so..." (the error)
```

Comment: `math.randomseed(os.clock() * 10000)` fails with "bad argument #1 to 'randomseed' (number has no integer representation)" in Lua 5.4.4 on Linux.

Comment: `math.randomseed(os.clock())` should work. 5.4 and it's darn ints :/ @DaveJarvis

Comment: Maybe revise your answer to help others who don't scroll down to see the comments?